# How to do Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) with ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, cors

I need to do a Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) by ajax POST request to an action of a controller class (MVC) of another domain site, This is to keepalive the session. How do I achieve this? I am using jQuery ajax call for this by setting cross-domain property to true.

It's better if you can show me a code example.

Scenario

Domain A ----> Ajax Call--> Domain B to keepAlive session of domain B, until user logout from Domain A. For this Ajax call I'm planning to use JS file inside domain B

Comment: Your statement **"Domain A ----> Ajax Call--> Domain B to keepAlive session of domain B, until user logout from Domain A. For this Ajax call i'm planning to use JS file inside domain B"** is totally self contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities. You can enable CORS on Domain B and use jQuery AJAX to access it. Note that CORS is supported only in modern browsers; especially only in IE 10+. IE8 and IE9 have XDomainRequest object, which you can use to do the same, but it has some limitations. See: http://caniuse.com/#search=cors.

Your second possibility is to use a dynamically created iframe and create a form inside there and post it to the domain B. The code would like something like this:

```
$("<iframe id='ifr' style='display:none;'></iframe>").appendTo("body");
var iframe = $("#ifr");

iframe.load(function () {
    //Do something after iframe has been sent
    //At least we need to remove the iframe
    iframe.remove();
});

var iframeContents = iframe.contents();
var iframeBody = iframeContents.find("body");
iframeBody.append("<form id='myForm' action='yourURLComesHere' method='post'></form>");
var iframeForm = iframeBody.children("form");

//If you need form values, you can do it like this:
iframeForm.append("<input type='hidden' name='inputName' value='inputValue' />");

iframeForm.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Domain A to Domain B (keepalive of Session): Too contradictory to share the sessions.

Should maintain [**Same Origin Policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) for Security feature [**CSRF**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/).

Answer (score -1):

You cannot send an Ajax call from a site in "DomainA" to a URL in "DomainB" the browser won't let you, this is a security feature.
What you can do is send an Ajax request to "DomainA" and have the server side relay that message to "DomainB".